# php artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

Bom dia a todos! Estou fazendo o curso de Laravel e na hora de tentar migrar para o banco de dados com o **php artisan migrate**, aparece esta mensagem de erro:

```
      INFO  Running migrations.

  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table .................................................................................. 6ms FAIL

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\Users\nanim\Documents\Alura\Laravel\controle-series\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:760     
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }
```

No curso, o instrutor faz a migração com o Sqlite, mas como eu tenho uma base com o MySql, preferi fazer com esta opção. Estou utilizando o MySql Workbench.

No arquivo .env , está assim:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=series
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Já usei o comando **php artisan make:migration create_series_table** pra criar o banco, que foi criado, mas ainda assim não está funcionando:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBkhK.png)

Alguém por favor poderia me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -2):

Esse erro acontece porque a tabela users já existe no seu banco e não foi criado o registro na tabela migrations, provavelmente por um erro...

Se ainda não está populada, apague manualmente a tabela `DROP TABLE users;` e tente novamente.

Caso ela esteja com registros e você tenha certeza que está ok, insira manualmente o nome do arquivo da sua migration de users `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table` na tabela migrations.